# How to compile Oracle 12c package file from client using Python 3.5

Tags: python, oracle, compilation, python-3.5, oracle12c

Using **Oracle 12cR1** and **Python 3.5**.

I have **Oracle** package files in client folders

Below is the package header with path

```
/fodler1/folder2/pkh/mypkg.sql
```

Below is the package body with path

```
/fodler1/folder2/pkb/mypkg.sql
```

I want to compile mypkg header and body in **Oracle** using **Python** script. Below is a modified form of the **Python** code I used.

```
import cx_Oracle as ora
conn = ora.connect("myuser/mypwd@myservice")
cur = conn.cursor()
with open("/fodler1/folder2/pkh/mypkg.sql","r") as sqlFile:
    sql = sqlFile.read()
    cur.execute(sql)
with open("/fodler1/folder2/pkb/mypkg.sql","r") as sqlFile:
    sql = sqlFile.read()
    cur.execute(sql)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

This doesn't seem to work. When I query `all_objects` in **Oracle**, the `status` shows as `INVALID`. When I compiled the header in **Oracle SQL Developer**, the header's `status` alone became `VALID`. Am I missing something? Is there a better way to achieve my objective?

Comment: Worked fine for me in Python 3.6.4 and cx_Oracle version 6.3.1. There should be some error with your package body. Please check.

Comment: The package header and body compiles successfully when I compile it from Oracle SQL Developer. But when I compile the same from python I get status as invalid in all_objects. The issue is with the final / included in the package header and body. In Oracle SQL Developer, this doesn't throw error. But when compiled from python it does. Found this out from USER_ERRORS. Currently using python rstrip() to trim the / before compiling. If there is a better way it would help.

Comment: Looks like you have a "/"  at the end of your `mypkg.sql` , which the sql driver doesn't recognise. Removing it should work .. Ok.. You got that one already!

Comment: careful with rstrip.. You may end up removing some genuine characters ..